# Burn true audio CDs in Linux

Tags: linux, audio, optical-media

I am searching for a software to burn true Audio CDs in Linux. I have some vintage CD players like Philips (1991) or Fisher (1987), and I want to burn some FLAC audio files to be able to play on these CD players.

I have tried Brasero, however it burns CD as WAV.

What software on linux do you recommend? I would like to be a high-quality lossless result.

Thanks!

**Note:** I read [Ripping software for audio CDs on Linux](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14239/ripping-software-for-audio-cds-on-linux) however it seems to be MP3 format. I am speaking about original Audio CD format, with lossless result.